# Array filter method to match IDs and check properties exist

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm currently using a method to try to filter some arrays, the method is almost working but I can't seem to access the exact values -

I make a call and add each returned array into a bigger array, these arrays will then be assigned a productId and maybe some data, i am appending the productIds using this:

```
    data.push({'productId':  product.id});
```

Which unfortunately adds a new object to the array which means my function below doesnt work unless the productId is in the first object of each array:

```
    let matchedArray = data.flatMap(arr => arr.filter(obj => obj.productId == id))
```

What I need to do is filter the array down to the subarray that matches the productId and ID and also that has some of the fields of data such as 'name' - so it checks that the name isnt empty.

The data set looks like this (array of subarrays)

```
  id = 12345


    data = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[{"id":"123","name":"africa soul 
    2019","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"country":null,"city":null,"type":"Ev
    ent","members":null},{"productId":"12345"}],[],[],[],[],[],[],
    [],[],[],[],[]]
```

As you can see the productId is appended to the array but isnt now working with my filter method, i need to filter for the right array that has matching ID's and at least one of the fields are also existing. I either need to change the way the productId is manually appended, or change the filter method?

Thanks so much if you can help

Comment: please post what's inside `data` in the question

Comment: I have, the data array is there data = [[],[],[],[... etc

Comment: why is the empty arrays pushed into data?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: expected output is the array that contains data - I get every array that is empty consoling instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) all the arrays which have [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) object which have a `productId` equal to a given value:

```js
let data = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[{"id":"123","name":"africa soul 2019","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"country":null,"city":null,"type":"Event","members":null},{"productId":"12345"}],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],
    id = "12345";

let filtered = data.filter(arr => arr.some(a => a.productId === id))

console.log(filtered)
```

If you want to get the first match, use `find` instead of `filter`